# Runtime Error: Main method not found in class ImageTool, please define the main method as: public static void main(String[] args)

Tags: java

Why does my code (compiles fine) gives me the following error?

> Main method not found in class ImageTool, please define the main method as:    public static void main(String[] args)

### Code:

```
public class ImageTool {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    if (args.length <1) {
        System.out.println("Please type in an argument");
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    if (args[0].equals("--dump")) {
        String filename = args[1];
        int[][] image = readGrayscaleImage(filename);
        print2DArray(image);
    } else if (args[0].equals("--reflectV")) {
        String filename = args[1];
        int[][] image = readGrayscaleImage(filename);
        int[][] reflect = reflectV(image); //reflectV method must be written
        String outputFilename = args[2];
        writeGrayscaleImage(outputFilename,reflect);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is why I hate eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Your main method looks fine.

1. Probably your .class file does not correspond to your .java file. I would try to clean up my project (if I was using an IDE and getting this). That is: delete the .class file, regenerate it from the .java file.
2. It seems you're not running ImageFile but some other class, even though you think you're running ImageFile. Check what your IDE is running behind the scenes.

Comment: might be noobish but how do regenerate it from the .java file

Comment: By compiling it. Just run `javac ImageTool.java` from the command line (as I am not sure if you're using an IDE or not).

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your help. That's what I thought, hasn't done anything though. So im kinda stuck =/

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20773888/error-main-method-not-found-in-class-textbook-please-define-the-main-method-as

Comment: Seems you're not running ImageFile but some other class, even though you think you're running ImageFile. Check what your IDE is running behind the scenes.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15383244/error-please-define-the-main-method-as-public-static-void-mainstring-args